# Disabled attribute with a reactive form directive button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
            <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" id="lastName"
            name="lastnamefield" />

            <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" id="firstName"
            name="firstnamefield" />

            <button pButton id="searchButton" [disabled]="isDone" (click)="handleClick()"></button>

</div>
```

This is how I create the form:

```
form = this.formbuilder.group({
  lastName: [{ value: undefined, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
  firstName: [{ value: undefined, disabled: false }],
});
```

I use the `handleClick()` to do some operations and then set the button and inputs to disabled like this:

```
    private handleClick(){
      // do some operations...
      isDone = true;
      this.form.get('firstName')?.disable();
      this.form.get('lastName')?.disable();
    }
```

I get a warning in the console:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive
> form directive. If you set disabled to true   when you set up this
> control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually
> be set in the DOM for   you. We recommend using this approach to avoid
> 'changed after checked' errors.

I tried adding the `[formcontrolname]` to the button, but apparently it is not possible. What should I do in this case or should I just ignore the warning?

Comment: This error is related to use the attribute disabled in a "input", not in a button, are you sure this error?

Comment: I think that is the original purpose of that error message, however, I think the way the error gets generated is it checks if there's a [disabled] being used inside a [formgroup] and this could be an edge case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead:

```
form = this.formbuilder.group({
  lastName: [{ value: undefined, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
  firstNames: [{ value: undefined, disabled: true }],
});
```

Comment: This is correct, but also remove the [disabled] from the html template code.